# After locking the table, I get warning

Tags: php, mysql, locking

This is my code

```
      $ar = ($_POST['ar']);
      $query = "lock table stock write";
      $res = mysqli_query ($db, $query);

        /*******Count******/
        $query = "SELECT SUM(quantita_vendita) AS somma FROM stock";
        $res = mysqli_query ($db, $query);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $somma = $row['somma'];

           if($ar<=$somma){
                $query = "SELECT * FROM user, info WHERE info.id_user = user.id and user.email = '{$_SESSION['email']}'";
                $res = mysqli_query ($db, $query);

                      if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
                                $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
                                $azioni = $row['azioni'];
                                $denaro = $row['denaro'];
                                $id = $row['id'];
                                mysqli_free_result($res);
                      }
```

If you do not insert the lock , it works. 
Instead when I insert the lock , I have a Warning (mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in..) for the `if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use table locking, you have to lock ALL tables you will use in any query in that session (or unlock them again), see [LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html)

> A session that requires locks must acquire all the locks that it needs in a single LOCK TABLES statement. While the locks thus obtained are held, the session can access only the locked tables. For example, in the following sequence of statements, an error occurs for the attempt to access t2 because it was not locked in the LOCK TABLES statement:
>
> ```
> mysql> LOCK TABLES t1 READ;
> mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t1;
> +----------+
> | COUNT(*) |
> +----------+
> |        3 |
> +----------+
> mysql> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t2;
> ERROR 1100 (HY000): Table 't2' was not locked with LOCK TABLES
> ```

So in your case, the query using table `user` and `info` failed. To solve that, use e.g.

```
lock tables stock write, user write, info write;
```

You got your error-message, because the query failed, and thus `$res` is false and not an `mysqli_result`-object, and therefore `mysqli_num_rows($res)` doesn't work. You should always check if a query failed before using the result, e.g. use

```
if ($res = mysqli_query($db, $query)) {
   if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {... }
} else {
   printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to a manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

> mysqli_query  Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

So instead of `if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0)` you should use `if ($res)`

Comment: It means that $res is false and your query is failed. Try to find an error with mysqli_errno @Peppifg

Comment: I tried the query directly on the db , and the query works

Comment: the query does not work only after locking the table stock (but in the db works also after locking table)